# XML - Deserialize property as Xml sub-tree

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

When I'm deserializing a xml string, I need to save a XElement outerXml on a string property called `prop2`.

**My XML:**

```
<MyObj>
  <prop1>something</prop1>
  <prop2>
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>...</Modulus>
      <Exponent>...</Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>
  </prop2>
  <prop3></prop3>
</MyObj>
```

**My object:**

```
public class MyObj
{
    [XmlElement("prop1")]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop3", IsNullable = true)]
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm deserializing using `XmlSerializer`, like this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(myXmlString));
```

I tried to use `[XmlText]` to save XML text in `prop2` But I'm only getting `null`.

What I need to do to save `<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>...</Modulus><Exponent>...</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>` like text in `prop2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: @MethodMan I don't see where there is the duplication... In that question they need to deserialize each xml element to a property, but I need to deserialize all RSAKeyValue outer xml to a single property as text string

Comment: @MethodMan believe me I already did since this morning. But my question is a particular problem.

Comment: Can't you just have custom class to read this properties (would be easier to do it that way and if you still need string - create extra non-serialized property to read it)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can but `[XmlText]` shouldn't do the trick? Because then I need to use `prop2` as string, always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlText` will give value as XML encoded as text (`"&gt;prop2&lt;..."`) see [XmlTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> By default, the XmlSerializer serializes a class member as an XML element. However, if you apply the XmlTextAttribute to a member, the XmlSerializer translates its value into XML text. This means that the value is encoded into the content of an XML element.

One possible solution - use `XmlNode` as type of the property:

```
public class MyObj
{
    [XmlElement("prop1")]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    public XmlNode prop2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop3", IsNullable = true)]
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

var r = (MyObj)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(myXmlString));
Console.WriteLine(r.prop2.OuterXml);
```

Alternatively you may make whole object implement custom Xml serialization or have custom type that matches XML (to read normally) and have additional property to represent that object as XML string.

Comment: I think he'd want the OutterXml rather than the InnerXml:

Inner: <Modulus>...</Modulus><Exponent>...</Exponent>
Outer: <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>...</Modulus><Exponent>...</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>

Comment: And if I use `public XmlNode prop2 { get; set; }` I get the exception `There was an error reflecting property 'prop2'`

Comment: Try just `[XmlElement] public XmlNode prop2 { get; set; }`

Comment: Still not working, I'm getting `The specified type is abstract: name='XNode', namespace='', at <prop2 xmlns=''>.` exception

Comment: That's strange, @Ninita. [This](http://paste.ee/p/qzNfK) is my full code, and it works as expected. Can you paste what you have?

Comment: @merthsoft now I deleted some namespaces like `System.Linq`, `System.Runtime.Serialization`and `System.Xml.Linq` and now it works!

Comment: @Ninita - just noticed that I have not removed `[XmlText]` from my sample which indeed would cause problem you originally got with my code (updated). Using just `[XmlElement]` would work too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I saw that. I saw [your code](http://paste.ee/p/qzNfK) and is equal to my, the only difference are the file namespaces, I had more. I just removed some of those namespaces and now it works.