# Parse XML in C# with children as String

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have the following XML structure:

```
<BaseResponse>
  <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
  <Text>success</Text>
  <DataObject>1111-1111-2222-121212-12121</DataObject>
</BaseResponse>
```

I am using `XmlSerializer` in C# to serialize the XML into a C# object:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string DataObject { get; set; }

    public static BaseResponse Get(string xmlResponse)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseResponse));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlResponse))
        {
            var responseObj = (BaseResponse)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
            return responseObj;
        }
    }
}
```

This works without any problems. But in certain cases the node `DataObject` includes children as well. For Example like this (can be any children really):

```
<BaseResponse>
  <Status>0</Status>
  <Text>success</Text>
  <DataObject>
    <DetailStatus>
        <Author>Peter</Author>
        <DateCreated>21.08.2021 19:00:05</DateCreated>
    </DetailStatus>
  </DataObject>
</BaseResponse>
```

Now, with my existing serializing mechanism this XML cant be parsed. Is there any way to tell the `XmlSerializer` to parse the children of the node `DataObject` as string if there are any. So that `BaseResponse.DataObject` would return the children nodes as string.

Like so:

`"<DetailStatus><Author>Peter</Author><DateCreated>21.08.2021 19:00:05</DateCreated></DetailStatus>"`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [XML - Deserialize property as Xml sub-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33741048/3744182) work for you?

Comment: There is also [How to prevent XmlSerialzer from escaping "nested XML"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38107517/3744182).

Comment: @dbc defining the property as type XmlNode works for me (your first link). thanks very much. wanna add it as answer, so I can accept it?